# How to print halftone from Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have a [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) file with image and text. I want to print it to a laser printer so that the images print in a halftone round pattern.

I am trying to print it from the command line. I would prefer a PDF output first and then I'll print to the laser printer.

I have an HP Laserjet P2015 printer installed in Windows 10.

```
gswin64c.exe -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf test.ps -c "<< /HalftoneType 1 /Frequency 37 /Angle 45 /SpotFunction {180 mul cos exch 180 mul cos add 2 div} >> sethalftone"
```

The PDF file is generated. However, the images does not appear to be in Round Halftone format. I see no change in the image.

[This is the original Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jghdcdumpxozhmm/original.jpg?dl=0)

I want the printout to look like this: [Required output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/29t0ih3lpwsz6eu/required.jpg?dl=0)

For some reason the output is the same as the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdfwrite doesn't create monochrome output, so no, the output won't be halftoned. The whole point of the pdfwrite device is to maintain the output as close in quality as possible to the input.

There is **no way** to get monochrome output from pdfwrite unless the monochrome is in the input.

If you instead use a monochrome output device (e.g., tiffg3 or tiffg4) you should see a difference, unless the input file (which you haven't supplied) also sets a screen, in which case the last one encountered will take effect. That is, if the PostScript input file specifies a halftone screen, that's the one that will get used.

What you are asking for is what I might generally describe as a hard problem, probably much harder than you expect.

Your best bet is to send the PostScript directly to the printer, since it supports PostScript.

Problem 1; your PostScript file may already contain a halftone in it which overrides the one you want to use. You can usually prevent that by redefining the sethalftone and setscreen operators:

/sethalftone {pop} bind def 
/setscreen {pop pop pop} bind def

You do that after you'[ve defined your own halftone, obviously. Or you can just edit the PostScript file and remove the halftone definition, its usually not that hard to find.

Problem 2 is that printer manufacturers sometimes 'tweak' the interpreter to always use their preferred halftone and prevent you overriding it in PostScript. The only way to find out if that's happening is to try a quick test; print a simple image with the default screen, then set a really coarse screen, say 10 lpi and print the same image. If there's no difference then you know that's not a viable option. If there is, then you can just set the screen you want.

Now, if the printer won't let you change the halftone then the only solution is to render the PostScript to an image using Ghostscript (which will let you change the halftone) and then send the resulting image to the printer. You will need to use a 1 bpp device, something like tiffg3 or tiffg4 should work fine.

The problem here is that you need to ensure that the image fits on the media of the printer, because if it doesn't then the likelihood is that the printer will slightly scale down the image so that it does fit, thereby squashing the halftone cells.

Even more subtly, the printable area of the media in the printer may not be the same as the size of the media. Paper handling can mean that there are some areas of the paper that can't be printed on, and the variability in the feeding of the paper can mean that the printer will refuse to print right to the edges anyway. Because if it did, and there was, say, a 1 mm deviation in the paper handling, then 1 mm of the edge would 'fall off' and there would be a 1 mm white gap at the other edge...

Comment: Hello KenS thanks for the reply. Ok, i'll skip pdf output. How do I output directly to laser printer with halftone? I have a grayscale image in Coreldraw. I created ps file from Coreldraw and what command to give at command prompt so that the output comes out in halftone with a frequency of 53.

Comment: Added to my answer too long for a comment

Comment: Hello KenS, thanks for the reply. I tried printing directly to printer from Coreldraw applcation, The frequency I gave was 50, but it does not print halftone. I have used HP Universal PS driver and also the stock driver. I have uploaded test.ps ps file in following link:     [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hih6t3ypclcdsb3/test.ps?dl=0)  I will be grateful to you if something can feasible can come out. My requirement is that I want to print this PS file directly to Laser Printer with Halftone Frequency of 50 lpi. All my images are grayscale. Coarse screen 10 lpi gives same output. No change.

Comment: Well the PostScript file doesn't contain a Hlftone definition, and doesn't perform an initgraphics, so simply sticking the halftone on the front of the file works for me. I'm not sure why you thinkyour printer isn't halftoning the output, it really must be. It may, of course, be using a different screening method, it could be using a stochastic screen or something. Anyway, if the printer won't execute a PostScript halftone then you are left with rendering it using Ghostscript to get an image, then opening the image with some application and printing it. You could probably use Corel for that.

Comment: Hello KenS, Thanks for the reply. I have created an EPS file this time and I see the code generated it totally different. Can it be edited to change the Halftone type to round and Frequency to 45-50 ?  I have uploaded the file. I pr [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsajahciqnttqns/testnew.eps?dl=0)     I opened the file in gsview and gave a print command to pdf and the output seems gud. The only thing i want here is that I want to change the halftone pattern from line to round or dot.  Here is the pdf file link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud7elhxi04kff7n/testnew.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: EPS files can't contain a halftone, that's illegal for EPS. The reason its 'totally different' is because you are using a totally different PostScript generator. Instead of Corel generating PostScript its the ps2write device from Ghostscript. I do not know what gsview is doing, but its either using the mswinpr2 device (and so having the printer halftone the output) or its sending it direct because its a PostScript printer. Its hard to see either way how you can be getting a different result from sending the PostScript file yourself!

Comment: Hello KenS, I was able to print halftone using following process :- I created a ps file wih 55 frequency from Coreldraw then I issued the command gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=ljet4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER  -sOutputFile="%printer%LAN_HP2015_PCL" test.ps and it worked. BUT for some reason when I print directly to the printer from coreldraw with 55 frequency using postscript driver, it does not work. I have to mirror this output also which I am working on now.

Comment: Well printing to PCL will actually render the PostScript to a big image, then wrap that up with enough PCL to send to a pritner. So in effect its what I was saying about rendering to an image.

Comment: Hello KenS, for some reason I see that when I print through command line, the page size differs. The output is approx 1cm shorter than the original. I tried this from Coreldraw and Indesign both. How can I cope this situation. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid its not possible to say. I don't know what command lin eyou are using, what input file and I don't know what you are comparing it to. Possibly the result of printing from an application. It would be a day or so research project even armed with all the above information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You are right KenS. It was my mistake. The pdf which i was printing had autosize one. I unchecked that and it works now. I have also managed both halftone and mirror the output at the same time. Thanks for your time and support.